# Daemon executes only one time a goroutine

Tags: go, time, daemon, goroutine

I try to add the necessary code to execute my app like a daemon. I used the next project:

- github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon

I rewrote the sample go code that it's done:
https://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon/blob/master/sample/sample.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon"
)

var (
    signal = flag.String("s", "", `sdaemon -s ...
        quit -- graceful shutdown`)
)

var (
    stop = make(chan struct{})
    done = make(chan struct{})
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    daemon.AddCommand(daemon.StringFlag(signal, "quit"), syscall.SIGQUIT, TermHandler)

    cntxt := &daemon.Context{
        PidFileName: "/var/run/sdaemon.pid",
        PidFilePerm: 0644,
        WorkDir:     "./",
        Umask:       027,
        Args:        []string{"[sdaemon]"},
    }
    if len(daemon.ActiveFlags()) > 0 {
        d, _ := cntxt.Search()
        daemon.SendCommands(d)
        return
    }
    d, err := cntxt.Reborn()
    if d != nil {
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer cntxt.Release()

    // Start daemon
    go Worker()

    err = daemon.ServeSignals()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("STOPPED!\n")
        return
    }
}

func Worker() {
    for {
        go Writer()
        if _, ok := <-stop; ok {
            break
        }
    }
    done <- struct{}{}
}

func TermHandler(sig os.Signal) error {
    stop <- struct{}{}
    if sig == syscall.SIGQUIT {
        <-done
    }
    return daemon.ErrStop
}
```

I have added a function `Writer()` that read a file, keep the text like a string and create a new file with this string.

```
func Writer() error {
    time.Sleep(time.Minute)

    f, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("$HOME/test")
    contents := string(f)

    fileHandle, _ := os.Create("$HOME/stest")
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(fileHandle)
    defer fileHandle.Close()
    fmt.Fprintln(writer, contents)
    writer.Flush()

    return nil
}
```

I don't handle so good the channels in golang and I don't know why the infinite loop for in `Worker()` function is executed only once...

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `Worker` function, when you try to check if you have any data in the `done` channel. The `receive`call will block until there is a value to be read, so that call will block until you send a signal to the process.

The second value returned from the receive operator, `ok`, does not indicate whether a value was succesfully read or not. It just indicates if the channel was closed when trying to receive a value (if so the `zero value` is returned, see [the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)).

To check if there is a value in the channel you need to use a `select` statement, like this:

```
select {
        case v, ok <- stop:
            // We could read a value from the channel
        default:
            // No value could be read, but we didn't block
}
```

So your `Worker` function should look something like:

```
func Worker() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Minute)
        select {
        case <- stop:
            // Got a stop signal, stopping
            done <- struct{}{}
            return
        default:
            // No stop signal, continuing loop
        }

        go Writer()
    }
}
```

Note that I have moved the `Sleep` from the `Writer` function to the `Worker`, otherwise you would end up with thousands of concurrent `Writer` go-routines...

Comment: Now the function `Writer()` works, but when I type `sdaemon -s quit` to do a graceful shutdown, it does not work, before it worked; You know what's the problem? Thank you so much for your first anwser @johlo

Comment: I have the answer, `sdaemon -s quit` works but we have to wait time.Sleep() to get the graceful shutdown. I need to change that.

Comment: @icvallejo You probablly want to use a `Ticker` instead of sleeping, see https://gobyexample.com/tickers. You can stop the ticker when the SIGQUIT signal comes.